# Modifying fetch response inside React UseEffect not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code where I try to call an API and modify the width and height (based on the original width and height values of the objects), and then set the state of one variable to that modified response

```
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      'https://api.example.com/photos'
    );

    res
      .json()
      .then(res => {
        const result = res.map((val, i) => {
          // val is like {'src': 'xxxx', width: 1000, height: 150}
          let height = 0;
          let width = 0;
          if (val.width > val.height) {
            width = 2;
            height = 1;
          } else {
            width = 1;
            height = 2;
          }
          return Object.assign(val, { width, height });
        });
        setPhotos(result);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

The `result` used in `setPhotos` has the original width and height, not the supposedly updated ones.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code as posted should not work the way you describe, maybe the code having the problem works different but as posted in question cannot have width and height of res.

Comment: @HMR the code I posted is what I have.. you can see that I am using `res.map` to get the height and width of each object in the res array.

Comment: Ok, post some code that actually does what you say goes wrong because what you post in the question works as expected. Run this in the console and tell me it doesn't set with and height: `[{'src': 'xxxx', width: 1000, height: 150}].map((val) => {
  let height = 0;
  let width = 0;
  if (val.width > val.height) {
    width = 2;
    height = 1;
  } else {
    width = 1;
    height = 2;
  }
  return Object.assign(val, { width, height });
});`

Comment: @HMR that's exactly the problem. As I commented on the answer below, if I isolate that map function in the console with the `res` array, it works correctly. That's why I am confused.

Comment: [Here is a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-react-webpack-2s2ny) showing the exact code you posted not having the behavior you describe. Please post the  code demonstrating the problem as code in your question **does not** have the problem you describe.

Comment: @AngularDebutant  can you show us all your component code?

Comment: You are mutating the original response, in code posted this doesn't matter but I'm quite sure that's not the actual code. If you don't want to mutate the response then you can do `Object.assign({},val, { width, height });` or `{...val,width,height}`